# Environment variable + robocopy

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, robocopy

I'm having trouble creating an environment variable to use with Robocopy.

I would like to create one variable that detects the drive letter where  CMD is open, to copy something from within a path of the disk drive itself to the folder where the prompt is open.

Something like that:

```
Name o variable: Test

Value of variable: robocopy /e /v /A-:SH "%cd:~0,2%\folder1\folder2" "."
```

But this way robocopy is not interpreting "%cd:~0,2%" as a variable.

I'm wrong where?

Comment: Replace dot with comma **"%cd:~0,2%"**

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong here, I already had a comma. The robocopy path is getting `"I:\folder1\folder2\%cd:~0,2%\folder1\folder2" "."` Note that `"I:\folder1\folder2\"` is the path where the CMD is open"

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is:
Copy some folders from the same drive where `cmd.exe` is open `(I:\folder4\folder5 - i.e. drive I: in this case)` to the folder where it is open `(I:\folder2\folder3)`. After I posted it here, I continued searching and saw that `%cd%` is not a windows variable and this could be one of the problems.

Comment: That is, copy the folders from the path `\folder4\folder5` that are on that same drive and paste in the folder where `cmd.exe` is open `I:\folder1\folder2`.

I believe that even though `%cd%` is not a windows variable but a `cmd.exe` variable, as the `%test%` variable applies the command in `cmd.exe` theoretically it could interpret `%cd%`, am I right?

Comment: The latest command in your question works both from a command line and batch file for me. How exactly are you executing the command?

Comment: That's the point, I'm not using batch files, the idea of ​​creating an environment variable is that it works as a shortcut for the command `robocopy /e /v /A-:SH "%cd:~0,2 %\folder1\folder2" "."`, that is, every time I type `%test%` run the command `robocopy /e /v /A-:SH "%cd:~0.2%\folder1\folder2" ". "`, works, but robocopy doesn't interpret `%cd:~0.2%` that way, which is quite curious since typing this same command directly at the command prompt everything works perfectly.

Anyway, I found a solution on the Microsoft forum, if it is useful to someone, follow the resolution below:

Comment: SOLUTION: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1062180/environment-variables-robocopy.html

Comment: @dno Directly at the command prompt, but through the environment variable. As I commented, the problem is when I run the command through the created environment variable, typing directly works perfectly.

Comment: As a side note, the root directory of the drive for the current working directory is always ```\```. So if your current working directory is `I:\mypath\mysub` and you wanted to reference `I:\folder4\folder5`, you could just use `\folder4\folder5`. Also, please use the syntax shown in the help information for the command `Robocopy "Source" "Destination" /Options`, not `Robocopy /Options "Source" "Destination"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma instead of decimal. %cd:~0,2%

```
robocopy /e /v /A-:SH "%cd:~0,2%\folder1\folder2" "."
```

If you do want to set a variable

```
set Test=%cd:~0,2%
robocopy /e /v /A-:SH "%Test%\folder1\folder2" "."
```